# How to display data retrieve from Json and display it according to html tag get from json

Tags: android, json

I want to display data in table format , here is my `JSON` response,

```
  [{
    "description": "<p>Payment Condition : Same Day</p>\r\n<table>\r\n    <tbody>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <th>Thickness</th>\r\n            <th>Edge</th>\r\n            <th>Width</th>\r\n            <th>Finish</th>\r\n            <th>Quantity about</th>\r\n            <th>Rate</th>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.3 mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>BA TWO SIDE</td>\r\n            <td>3 ton</td>\r\n            <td>131</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.3mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>BA TWO SIDE</td>\r\n            <td>100 kg</td>\r\n            <td>133</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.4mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>BA TWO SIDE</td>\r\n            <td>3 ton</td>\r\n            <td>129</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.4mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>BA TWO SIDE</td>\r\n            <td>100 kg</td>\r\n            <td>131</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.4mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>2B Finish</td>\r\n            <td>3 ton</td>\r\n            <td>125</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.5mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>BA TWO SIDE</td>\r\n            <td>3 ton</td>\r\n            <td>125</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.5mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>BA TWO SIDE</td>\r\n            <td>100 kg</td>\r\n            <td>127</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.5mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510mm</td>\r\n            <td>2B Finish</td>\r\n            <td>3 ton</td>\r\n            <td>122</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.6mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510/485mm</td>\r\n            <td>2B Finish</td>\r\n            <td>3 ton</td>\r\n            <td>120</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.7 to 1.5mm</td>\r\n            <td>Mill edge</td>\r\n            <td>510/485mm</td>\r\n            <td>2B Finish</td>\r\n            <td>3 ton</td>\r\n            <td>118</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n        <tr>\r\n            <td>0.6 to 1.5mm</td>\r\n            <td>Slit edge</td>\r\n            <td>38 to 238mm</td>\r\n            <td>2B Finish</td>\r\n            <td>100 kg</td>\r\n            <td>122</td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n    </tbody>\r\n</table>",
    "error": false,
    "message": "RESULT_OK",
    "photo": "http://derk.jbsoftware.co.in/products/smallphoto/20c6ec1f-e858-41ac-9383-4a47e25a2939.jpg",
    "product_id": "1",
    "title": "S.S. 201 COIL"
  }]
```

In description html tag table, p, tr,td use I want to display data according to html tag if table tag  than table create and set data from tr and td tag  according to table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: check this out https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview

Comment: no my question is different  I want to display data in table format according to json response . show description data.

Comment: So basically you want to use HTML tags in Android, to have same result as if you'd use those tags on Webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your problem. You have to to `Html.fromHtml(youstrinf)` to achieve this.

> txtViewdescrip.setText(Html.fromHtml(description));

By using this all the `HTML` tags remove and it format your `String` in HTML format.